# How to prevent a user from being redirected to a link in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

```js
var $ = function (id) {
    "use strict";
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('redirect').click(function () {
        window.alert('you clicked the link');
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

```html
 <a href="http://www.google.com" id="redirect">Visit Goggle</a>
```

I have a link in HTML and I wanting to use JavaScript and Jquery for the rest of my code. When the user clicks on the link, I want an alert to pop up with a message but I do not want the link to redirect them to that page. When I view my code in Chrome with the developer tools, I get an error message that says "Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property of 'ready' of null". Why is the ready property coming up null and how do I fix it?

```js
var $ = function (id) {
    "use strict";
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

$(document).ready (function () {
    "use strict";
    $('redirect').click(function () {
        window.alert('you clicked the link');
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

```html
 <a href="http://www.google.com" id="redirect">Visit Goggle</a>
```

`

Comment: You're attempting to reassign jQuery's `$` - don't do this. Also make sure you're using jQuery: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `e.preventDefault()`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#redirect').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.alert('you clicked the link');   
    }); 

});
```

Also, if you need to reference elements by class (with jQuery):

```
$('.someClass').on('click', function() {
 ...
```

If you want to access them 
by id:

```
$('#someId').on('click', function() {
...
```

Comment: Even when I use this method, it gives me the same error message of Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'ready' of null.

Comment: Did you add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>` at the bottom of your html page?

Comment: Also, make sure you remove the `var $ = function(id) {` function

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you're redefining jQuery's `$` function to your own custom function. Don't do this! It completely nullifies jQuery (you'd have to use the verbose `jQuery` form). You can also use `preventDefault` to prevent the hyperlink changing your page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('redirect').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.alert('you clicked the link');
    }); 
});
```

Also make sure you have jQuery - place this at the top of your page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $ = function (id) {
    "use strict";
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

If you use `$` as your jQuery wrapper, then the code above override that variable. Meaning it's no longer jQuery but rather that custom function that you have set. Try changing the name of the function or variable above.